# c++ sorting vector pairs quickly as part of a genetic learning algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I have a very interesting problem, I've started developing a genetic learning algorithm and have succeeded on doing so. its a simple GA designed to find a phrase by randomly selecting characters to store into strings and using the standard selection and mutation methods to progress until the it has the final answer, and sometimes this works perfectly.

However, sometimes there's one character incorrect.
I think this is due to the sorting algorithm being slow.
this is what i have so far

This is the loop code

```
while (!word.Get_found())
{
    generation++;
    word.Calculate_fitness();
    word.Selection();   //selection
    word.Crossover();   //crossover

    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Generation: " << generation << " Highest fitness: " << word.get_fittest() << " with string: " << word.get_item() << "\n";
}
```

This is the code for the fitness function

```
void Guess_word::Calculate_fitness()// calculates fittness based on guess 

word against matching string;
{
    for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++)
    {
        population.at(i).second = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < population.at(i).first.size(); j++)
        {
            if (population.at(i).first.at(j) == Phrase.at(j))
            {
                population.at(i).second += 1;//calculate fitness
            }
        }
        if (population.at(i).second == Phrase.size() && population.at(i).first == Phrase)
        {
            found = true;
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the selection function

```
void Guess_word::Selection()//determine highest fitness of population and make them parents
{
    //i hate stable sort....
    //it indicates to sort in pairs and keep them together
    std::sort(population.begin(), population.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.second > b.second; });


    //select two random parent from mating pool
    parents.clear();

    parents.push_back(population.at(0));
    parents.push_back(population.at(1));
}
```

The population entities are in vector pairs with strings and ints representing the guess and fitness respectively.
after debugging the code i found that the population does indeed contain the correct guess but with the wrong fitness, i think the sorting algorithm moves the ints faster than the paired strings. meaning that during the fitness function it selects an item as the answer that is one character incorrect however with the correct fitness moved from another vector entity.

I've tried using stable sort and moving the algorithm around to see if timing is a problem. however, no dice. 
is there a way to either make the program wait for the sort to complete (which is inefficient in terms of time) or a way to either make the sort faster or implement a faster custom sorting algorithm which would be much more efficient especially on older hardware.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in that loop in `Calculate_fitness()`, `i` will always be greater than or equal to 0 and less than `population.size()`, because that's what the loop says. All those bounds checks (`population.at(i)`) are pointless because `i` will always be in bounds. `population[i]` works just fine.

Comment: @PeteBecker ah thank you, I've not used vectors before and wasn't following a great tutorial, i'm changing that now thank you !

Comment: There's nothing in this code that's time-sensitive. Why would slow sorting affect the result?

Comment: What exactly are the definitions for `population`, `Guess_word` and `Phrase`? Can you provide (minimal) self-contained example code? You probably have an error somewhere in there.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm think that because of the while loop, i think it breaks before it can finish sorting.

Comment: @eukaryota population is defined as `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> population; ` `Guess_word` is simply a class that stores all the functions and private variables and `phrase` is simply a string which in the case of my algorithm is `"Ai is the best ever!" ` which is defined in the main.cpp and passed to the guess word cpp where its stored and used to determine the fitness of each guess

Comment: @AlexNotTheLion -- re: "it breaks before it can finish sorting" -- not with the code you've shown. The code in the while loop calls `word.Selection()`. `word.Selection()` does the sorting, then does some more stuff. When it's finished it returns, and the code in the `while` loop goes on, calling `word.Crossover()`. Everything here just goes one step after another; `word.Selection()` won't return before the sort has been done, and the `while` loop won't do anything until `word.Selection()` returns.

Comment: @PeteBecker okay, that must mean the sort isnt working correctly or the fitness function is wrong

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], the problem is more likely to be in your code than a bug in `std::sort`

Comment: @AlanBirtles the error only occurs on slower systems, on my personal home pc, the issue never occurs which makes me think its more timing than anything else

Comment: If you aren't using multiple threads its unlikely to be a timing issue. If you have undefined behaviour its entirely possible it will work by chance on one machine and not another. Without a [mcve] its difficult to tell where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was simply, the code doing a cross over and storing it back in position 0 of the population making it change randomly just before the final result was displayed